# Theme has disappeared

Tags: theme-development

I have spent years building up my word press site using a theme I paid for

Today it’s disappeared and it’s reverted to a sort of blank looking theme called twenty twenty one!

Does anyone know what has happened?

I had the theme dyad 2 before

Comment: If you have backups you can revert back to them. Check under wp-content/themes/, to see if the theme is there, maybe the name was changed. Check the style.css to see if the name is equal to the theme folder name.

Comment: Do you mean your theme files have actually disappeared from disk? Where did you get it from? I expect you can download a fresh copy, or email their support and ask for one.